# TDPDF Large Table, how to break it up so I can reuse same header on each page

Tags: php, tcpdf

Is there a way in TCPDF to insert a header on each page? I have a large table that spans multiple pages, but I need to have the same header on each page, just like the footer. Is there a way to do this? (Note: The header is dynamic content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set in in `thead` and it works out-of-the box I gather (since 4.5.030).

Comment: could you provide a small example of using thead?

Comment: The header would have to go above the table that spans multiple pages for each page. Kind of like the Header function override, but the data needs to be dynamic.

Comment: So it cannot be part of a table header? Why not? If you don't like the 'format', you can just give in another appearance? Or does it require to be outside the normal page margins?